# Can't instantiate multiple VFP COM Dlls: 80004005 Unspecified error

Tags: c#, com-interop, visual-foxpro, visual-foxpro-9

I've got two sample VFP9 `OlePublic` dlls that I'm calling from a .NET Core 2.1 project running full framework .NET 4.6.1.  Everything is working fine locally but upon deployment to a Windows Server 2016 machine, I'm only able to instantiate an instance of a.dll or b.dll, not both.  It seems the last one to be registered wins.

If I register a.dll then b.ll, I can instantiate an instance of b & vice versa.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CF0998BA-54F1-40BD-BB92-4E938A77E1E5} failed due to the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).

```
Define Class miked As Session OLEPUBLIC
    
FUNCTION HelloWorld as String
    RETURN "Hello World"
ENDFUNC 

FUNCTION Echo(thingToEcho as String) as String
    RETURN thingToEcho
ENDFUNC 

Enddefine
```

```cs
public void TestMikeDll()
{
    new miked.miked();
}
```

I'm guessing I haven't configured/defined something correctly in my VPF9 projects?

---

publish profile:

[image: screenshot of publish profile]

---

*update*

So it's **not** the last one registered, it's the **first** one to get instantiated.  If I successfully instantiate a.dll then b.dll fails but if I recyle the app pool & try b.dll first it succeeds & a.dll fails.

Comment: Have you tried building in X86?

Comment: yes, the project is set to `x86` and deployment as well; question updated.  @viveknuna

Comment: the 5 of the error code is the Win32 error code which means access denied. I would run procmon and watch for registry/file accesses which fail. That should hint to the right direction what went wrong.

Comment: thanks @AloisKraus, that did the trick!!  how did you know the `5` means access denied? 

Comment: It does not mean "access denied".  E_FAIL is a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting.

Comment: @spottedmahn: Hans is right, that E_FAIL is 0x80004005L, but E_ACCESSDENIED is defined slightly different as 0x80070005L. Still whenever I see a 5 at the end (at least for memory dumps where it is access denied, but that is another error code) the chances are high that somewhere something else did go wrong due to access issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the AppPool identity **write** (maybe modify too) **access** to the location of the VFP COM Dlls.  Apparently, it needs to dynamically create another DLL: `[original name]r1.dll` that has a file desc of "*Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9.0 SP2 Runtime Library*" (the purple box).

[image: change permissions screenshot]

1. Go to properties on folder where COM DLLs live
2. Security Tab
3. Edit
4. Add
5. in *enter the object names to select*: `IIS AppPool\[your AppPool name]`

reference: [MSFT doc page on giving AppPool identity file permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#securing-resources)

---

credit: [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74172087/cant-instantiate-multiple-vfp-com-dlls-80004005-unspecified-error?noredirect=1#comment130955800_74172087) from Aloio Kraus lead me down the path:

> the 5 of the error code is the Win32 error code which means access denied. I would run [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and watch for registry/file accesses which fail. That should hint to the right direction what went wrong

[image]

Comment: I **think** my real problem was [my install not finding some runtime DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74186260/185123)