# VFP dll not searching program files for vpf9r.dll

Tags: installshield, com-interop, visual-foxpro, windows-server-2016, visual-foxpro-9

When I try to instantiate a VFP COM (`OlePublic`) DLL from my .NET web app running in IIS on Windows server 2016 I get:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A55C4127-DDCB-4E5F-B69C-A7EAC83A83DC} failed due to the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).

I was able to track it down (using [Simon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173379/how-to-package-and-deply-a-vfp-olepublic-com-object/74174446#comment130958247_74173379)) to it not being able to find `vfp9r.dll`:

[image: failed to find vfp9r.dll screenshot from procmon]

Those files got installed w/ my InstallShield package under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VFP`:

- vfp9r.dll
- VFP9RENU.dll
- vfp9t.dll

[image: screenshot of installshield package]

---

Why isn't "it" searching that dir?  I got one server it is finding them under program files and another that isn't.  How does that magic work?

---

**update**

if I install VFP 9, it will search that dir & successfully load it.  So what is the VFP 9 install doing to my machine to tell "it" to search that dir not just the current dir & `\SysWow64`?

[image: search common dir screenshot]

[image: load image screenshot]

Comment: See https://github.com/VFPX/VFPRuntimeInstallers - `VfpX` is the semi-official community home since MS support ended

Comment: That is access denied error. The account executing it do not have access to that folder?

Comment: thanks @CetinBasoz, unfortunately I've learned that message happens for numerous reasons w/ these VFP com dlls.  I did double check read permissions `common files` and the app pool has read rights.  Also, I don't see it trying to read from that path in procmon.

Comment: I have found in the past that if you rebuild a COM dll, many times the registry gets stupid on who has permissions and such.  It has been as simple as going back into permissions and re-selecting the user account and possibly re-entering the password and it auto-magically works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**workaround**

import these registry keys:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VisualFoxProRuntimeMT.9\Shell\Open\Command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\VFP\\vfp9t.dll"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VisualFoxProRuntime.9\Shell\Open\Command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\VFP\\vfp9r.dll"
```

(save the above 'script' as a `.reg` file and double click it to import it)

---

**how I figured this out:**

- [Hyper-V checkpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints) so I could quickly go back and forth from a working to a non-working vm along w/ resetting after I did some test to find the minimal workaround
- [Search & export registry](https://superuser.com/a/1486972/40715) key w/ `vfp9r.dll` or `vfp9t.dll`
- Compare exports [via Notepad++ Compare Plus Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73822677/185123)
- The diff for `vfp9t.dll` was smaller so that was helpful.  I grabbed the first key and that worked.  Then I searched for the same-ish path for the `vfp9r.dll` export and grabbed that key.